# Command to remove a ssh authorized key on server

Tags: ssh

Is there a command (or a one-liner) to remove a ssh key on a server? Something like the opposite of ssh-copy-id?

Comment: Some SSH server software support the RFC 4819 protocol for managing authorized SSH keys, but it's so rare it's almost nonexistent on Linux :(

Comment: Excellent question, this is really missing functionality to ssh-copy-id to facilitate key rotation.

Comment: Its worth noting that [`ssh-keygen` does provide the `-R` option](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) for removing keys from `known_hosts`, but sadly `ssh-keygen -R <HOSTNAME> -f ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` doesn't work.  I would use the `sed` option below, instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Ignatio suggested this can be done with `grep -v`.

Here is a example which removes the key containing `some unique string` or just deletes the `authorized_keys` file when no other key remains.

```bash
if test -f $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys; then
  temp_file=$(mktemp)
  if grep -v "some unique string" $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys > $temp_file; then
    cat $temp_file > $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys && rm $temp_file;
  else
    rm $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys && rm $temp_file;
  fi;
fi
```

Replace `some unique string` with something that only exists in the key you wish to remove.

As a oneliner over ssh this becomes

```bash
ssh hostname 'if test -f $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys; then temp_file=$(mktemp); if grep -v "some unique string" $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys > $temp_file; then cat $temp_file > $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys && rm $temp_file; else rm $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys && rm $temp_file; fi; fi'
```

Tested on Linux (SLES) and HP-UX.

Comment: see below answer: `sed` is better at doing this

Answer (score 43):

`sed` provides a compact solution:

```
sed -i.bak '/REGEX_MATCHING_KEY/d' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

This will save the original `authorized_keys` in `authorized_keys.bak`. If you don't want the backup then just change `-i.bak` to `-i`.

You can even remove multiple keys:

```
sed -i.bak '/REGEX1/d; /REGEX2/d' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

The only tricky bit here is [special characters in the regex need to be escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/q/407523/1574959).

Comment: If you only use the base64 characters in the public keyfile (e.g., `awk '{print $2}' ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`), then you don't need to worry about escaping any special characters.

Comment: @Juan The important special character in base64 is "`/`" that must be escaped by "`\/`" for `sed` regexp. (Also a character "`+`" is possible in the output of base64, but it is not a special character if extended POSIX regular expressions that are not enabled by `-E` option in sed.) It is usually easier to use the comment field, especially if the default form user@host is used.

Answer (score 9):

Nope. You'll need to SSH in and use `sed` or `grep` to remove the key from the file.

Comment: Thank you. I will keep the question open a little longer to see if someone also can provide a script that does the opposite of ssh-copy-id

Comment: @grm : I'd suggest you keep the question open forever, or at least until a ssh-undo-copy-id is implemented ! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Phil already answered this question but I want to do addition and make it easier for you. And since you are asking reverse of ssh-copy-id, I am assuming you want to run it on authorized machine.

ssh keys only contains [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) characters. So you can use a char as sed delimiter that not in that list. Let us use '#'.

```
ssh root@<hostname> -o PasswordAuthentication=no "sed -i.bak 's#`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`##' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Replace hostname with the server IP.

PasswordAuthentication option will cause ssh fail if it ask password

Comment: The 'comment' in the pub key might not have base64 characters.  If it has a "#", then your example breaks.  Maybe use `awk '{print $2}' ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` with some `sed` or `grep -v` instead.